# Combine distinct list of dict with ansible

Tags: python, ansible

I have two list in ansible:

```
toto:
  - name: titi
  - name: tata

titi:
  - name: titi
    ack: true
```

Is it possible to combine these two lists by the name key to get the following:

```
new_list:
  - name: titi
    ack: true
  - name: tata
```

I found the way to combine dict, to combine list, by I don't know if I can do the following.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Q: `Is it possible to combine these two lists by the name key?`

A: Yes. It  is possible with the filter [selectattr](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#selectattr). The tasks below

```
- set_fact:
    new_list: "{{ new_list|default([]) +
                  [ item|
                    combine(titi|selectattr('name', 'match', item.name)|
                    list) ] }}"
  loop: "{{ toto }}"
- debug:
    var: new_list
```

give

```
"new_list": [
    {
        "ack": true, 
        "name": "titi"
    }, 
    {
        "name": "tata"
    }
]
```